# How to get every hop info from http

Tags: http, routes

I want to get every hop info(ip address, timestamp...) from http request or response, But I found not in httproute, Do you have solution to get every hop info from http content? Thanks.

**Updated**

Sorry for this question is not very clear.
I want to get the packet network path in server, and choice CDN based on those data.
So I need to get every route node the packet transmit from client to server, the ip address and timestamp. Is it clearly? My poor english.... Sorry again!

Comment: Hard to tell what you actually mean by "hop info"... I suggest you take a look at the `traceroute` command, it can work on different ports.

Comment: hop info means every hop from client to server(use http protocol), I want to get every hop info in route, do not add extra code like traceroute. I know the ip header include record route info, but how to get it?

Comment: A packages routing info cannot speak for the communication stream. It only describes this single package. Different packages might travel different routes. Traceroute is a reliable tool to test connection routing on a stochastic base.

Comment: I want to get every hop info in server, and client developed by others, http is the communication protocol between client and server.

Comment: Maybe I must use tcpdump to catch ip header in server?

Comment: You can do that. Sure. If you feel like...